# Select a list only if it matches with the other lists [SQL]

Tags: mysql

question for you

Imagine you've got a table, in this table, there is two ids, id_cat, id_hooman.

the column, id_hooman, is also on an other table, where there is "id_hooman, id_rights_given, id_house"

I would like to create an sql select, that would select all the id_house in commun with a list of id_cat.

Basically, I've got an array of idea_cat, and I want, at the end, an array of all the id_house shared by the id_cat in the first array.

I'm a newb in sql, and that's a little tricky for me, so thx for your help !

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info)

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful for your problem: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: I'm looking on it, it seems cleary usefull for what I'm trying to do